# sum of the cloc blank, comment , code in csv output

Tags: git, diff, cloc

by typing `cloc --vcs git`  i can get following output,

```
      12 text files.
      12 unique files.                              
       3 files ignored.

github.com/AlDanial/cloc v 1.78  T=0.06 s (140.8 files/s, 10839.6 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ant                              1             22              9            197
XML                              4             52             79            159
Java                             3             16             34             73
Markdown                         1             10              0             42
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                             9            100            122            471
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

cloc includes the package of output formats like `csv,xml,yml etc.` under following command `cloc --vcs git --csv --out"file.csv"` i can get all values to the csv file of the above output but ***not inlcuding*** `SUM:              9            100            122            471` values. is there anyway to get the **`SUM`** of the **blank , comment, code** values to csv output.

Answer (score 0):

The summation should be there.  I opened https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc/issues/343 for this; should see a fix later this weekend.

Comment: The fix was committed 5 days ago.  You can get it from the git master branch at https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc/blob/master/cloc